# MVC Core 6 and EF 6 Database First Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I am migrating a project from a .NET MVC5 EF6 to a MVC core 6 EF6 project. I been hunting for some guidance on how to scaffold the model from the SQlServer database. In this [link](https://www.yogihosting.com/database-first-approach-entity-framework-core/), it says to run this command in the "Package Manager Console".

```cs
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=vaio;Database=Company;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

When I run that command (with my correct connection string), I get the error

```cs
dotnet : Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
```

From other references I have found, it appears that this scaffolding supposedly works, but all the references are for older versions of .NET Core. On the Microsoft website tutorial, they even state...

> This tutorial has not been updated for ASP.NET Core 6. The ASP.NET Core 6 web templates use the new minimal hosting model, which unifies Startup.cs and Program.cs into a single Program.cs file. Until this tutorial is updated, see Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core - Tutorial 1 of 8 and Part 4, add a model to an ASP.NET Core MVC app on how to use EF with the new minimal hosting model. Updating the tutorial for ASP.NET Core 6 is tracked in this GitHub issue.

Is there a working scaffolding command for entity framework using the database first model?

Is there any good reference material that is current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking, this is the new reference...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext

The error came from using a deprecated function.

`Scaffold-DbContext` is the new command instead of `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`

Answer (score 0):

> When I run that command (with my correct connection string), I get the
> error dotnet : Could not execute because the specified command or file
> was not found.

Have you  installed the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package before running that command?

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold
> "Server=vaio;Database=Company;Trusted_Connection=True;"
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models

Check your server address. Read [dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) to know more.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Apparently there is no such thing as Entity Framework as it was done prior to core. I enjoy using the database diagram tool, but all of the updating is done through the command line now. The error came from the wrong command which changed recently in .NET6.